# What does the console's output means after defining a module?

Tags: elixir

Defining a module in console produces some collection of numbers with the module's function and number of arguments it takes:

```
defmodule HotelRoom do
  def book(%{name: name, age: age}) when age < 25, do: IO.puts "#{name}, you are too young"
  def book(%{name: name, age: age}) when age >= 30, do: IO.puts "#{name},you are 30 years old"
  def book(person), do: IO.puts "Your name is #{person.name}"
end

#=> {:module, HotelRoom,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 8, 120, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68,99, 0, 0, 0,
   150, 131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100,
   111, 99, 115, 95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>, {:book, 1}}
```

What does it mean and should I care about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the binary contents for the module. Normally you don't need to worry about it.

> This macro defines a module with the given alias as its name and with
>   the given contents. It returns a tuple with four elements:
>
> - :module
> - the module name
> - the binary contents of the module
> - the result of evaluating the contents block

http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.html#defmodule/2